# set drawable image to imageview with a path sqlite

Tags: java, android

I would appreciate if you could help me with this, I'm trying to show pictures from my drawable folder, and the names of those images are in a sqlite database.

The problem is that I can't apply the image on the imageview. Any idea about why this happened. Thanks

This is my code

setviewholder.java

```
public class SetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public ImageView txt_imagen;
public TextView txt_path_imagen;

public SetViewHolder (View itemView){
super(itemView);
txt_imagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_imagen);
txt_path_imagen = (TextView) itemView.findById(R.id.txt_path_imagen);
}
```

custom_list_item2.xml

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/txt_imagen"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public void onBindViewHolder(SetViewHolder holder, final int position){
  holder.txt_path_imagen.setText(items.get(position).getPath_imagen());
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("ar.com.allnight.allnight:drawable/"+items.get(position).getPath_imagen());
  holder.txt_imagen.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

the log:

```
Unable to decode the stream: java.ioFileNotFoundException: /ar.comm.allnight:drawable/imgage1
```

I have tried many different ways, but I can´t make it work and the others vars shows ok!, So now it is everything else work ok.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try this Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "drawable", getPackageName()));

Comment: I cant make it work, i have seen several examples use, but both use: getDrawable and getResources are deprecated, can you reformulate the code, im usiang AndroidStudio 2.2

Comment: use this ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);